# How can I put this program in a python function?

Tags: python, file

Sorry if I did someting wrong, is my first post.

I want to know how can I put this program in a def function.

thanks in advance.

```
    file = open("Moradores.txt", "a+")
    file1 = open("Moradores.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
    lerFile = file1.read()
    mName = input("Nome: ")
    if mName in lerFile:
        while True:
            print("O nome ja existe, tente outro")
            mName = input("Nome: ")
            if mName not in lerFile:
                break
    mEmail = input("Email: ")
    mPass = input("Senha: ")
    file.write(mName + "|")
    file.write(mEmail + "|")
    file.write(mPass + "|")
    file.write("\n")
    print("Continue registering?")
    print("1 - YES || 2 - NO")
    choice = input()
    if choice == '2':
        break
    elif choice != '1':
        print("Invalid option")
        print("Continue registering?")
        print("1 - YES || 2 - NO")
        choice = input()
        file.close()
```

Comment: Just write `def your_function():` at the start?

Comment: It depends on why you want this as a function. It is most of the time because we want to *parameterize* the code. What do you want as parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared the body of the function, you are just missing the function declaration for the most simple case (i.e. the one without arguments):

```py
def do_something():
    while True:
        file = open("Moradores.txt", "a+")
        file1 = open("Moradores.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
        lerFile = file1.read()
        mName = input("Nome: ")
        if mName in lerFile:
            while True:
                print("O nome ja existe, tente outro")
                mName = input("Nome: ")
                if mName not in lerFile:
                    break
        mEmail = input("Email: ")
        mPass = input("Senha: ")
        file.write(mName + "|")
        file.write(mEmail + "|")
        file.write(mPass + "|")
        file.write("\n")
        print("Continue registering?")
        print("1 - YES || 2 - NO")
        choice = input()
        if choice == '2':
            break
        elif choice != '1':
            print("Invalid option")
            print("Continue registering?")
            print("1 - YES || 2 - NO")
            choice = input()
            file.close()
```

If you need additional arguments, declare it in the function declaration in this way:

```py
def do_something(arg1, arg2, ...):
```

The simplest declaration which fits your code is this

```py
def do_something():
```

(of course you can change the name of the function)

You can read more on functions [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Just write your code like below, you've to just add a function declaration line:

```
def function_name():
    #then your code here with proper indentation

#calling your function to perform defined task
function_name()
```